# shorter solution

Tags: polynomials

I have a equation and I've found it's solution but it took two pages. It will help if it has a shorter solution which I couldn't find. 
Equation is $\frac{a}{ax-1}\times\frac{b}{bx-1} = ab$. Please guide me.

Comment: "a/(ax-1)   b/(bx-1) = a b" is not an equation that makes any sense!!!

Comment: @AtulMishra Is there a symbol in between $\frac{a}{ax-1}$ and $\frac{b}{bx-1}$? Or are you implying that these two are multipled together?

Comment: @barakmanos: It might be written in a confusing manner but if you interprete it as $\frac{a}{ax-1}\frac{b}{bx-1}=ab$ it makes sense. Or, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @MrYouMath: Then I would expect to see a "*" there.

Comment: Hi @atul mishra and Welcome to MSE, Take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and read some questions/answers. These things will help you in understanding the working of site in a better way.

Comment: @Rohan are you sure the OP meant multiple? As a multiplication question it is not too hard and I find it odd he would need two pages. As an addition question it is harder and could conceivable need more paper.

Comment: Maybe it is better to leave it till the OP clarifies his stand.

Comment: @Rohan Based on the OPs comments down below you were correct. I've re-rollbacked to your edit.

Comment: You must know the question before editing it

Comment: @HarshKumar I think we should wait for the OP to edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the equation as $ \frac {a}{ax-1} \cdot \frac{b}{bx-1}=ab\ $ then a solution is:

$ \frac {a}{ax-1} \cdot \frac{b}{bx-1}=ab\ $


$ \cdot \frac {1}{ab} $


$ \frac {1}{ax-1} \cdot \frac {1}{bx-1}=1\ $


$ \cdot (bx-1) $


$ \frac {1}{ax-1}=bx-1 $


$ (ax-1)(bx-1)=1 $


$abx^{2}-ax-bx+1=1$


$abx^{2}-x(a+b)=0$


$x(abx-a-b)=0$


$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x= 0& & \\
 x=\frac {a+b}{ab}&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: yes I've found the same 
but in a long manner
thanks

Comment: @AtulMishra If this answer is what you are after please click the Accept Answer button next to the Question. If it helped you then also consider clicking the up arrow to indicate it is a good answer.